# commands.getstatusoutput fails saying sh: Syntax error: ";" unexpected

Tags: python

I am running mongoimport command using python commands module as

```
status = utilities.execute(mongoimport)
```

in **utilities.py**

```
def execute(command):
    if not command:
        return (-1, 'command can not be empty or null')
    return commands.getstatusoutput(command)
```

When I run this, I see error as

```
sh: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

I see that [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html) says :

```
commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
Execute the string cmd in a shell with os.popen() and return a 2-tuple (status, output). cmd is actually run as { cmd ; } 2>&1, so that the returned output will contain output or error messages
```

How can I fix this to be able to run this command?

Comment: [commands](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html) was deprecated in 2.6, removed in 3.x, use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.htm)

```
from subprocess import check_output
output = check_output(["ls", "-l"])
```

This will raise an error if the command fails - no need to check for empty string.  If you are really sure that you want to pass stuff through the shell then call like this

```
output = check_output("ls -l", shell=True)
```

Just note that passing stuff through the shell is an excellent vector for security problems.